# Linq: How to Assign to Related Entities?

Tags: linq

How do I assign to an entity's related objects in a simple way?

```
properties=IList<property>
```

linq Entities:
People

People.Properties

To assign properties list to People.Properties, some properties may be new and others may already exist. How do I assign each property to the People.Property in a simple way?

Answer (score 1):

As long as your Property class is comparable using the default equality comparer, you should be able to take the set union and assign it to the properties collection.

```
People.Properties = People.Properties.Union( properties );
```